# Possible to show some dot files in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, .htaccess, terminal, hidden-files

I wanted to see the .htaccess files on my Mac (in the Finder). So I enabled the ShowAllFiles from the Terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

It works like expected but the downside is that I'm seeing all the .DS_Store and .localized files.

Is there a way to only show the files named .htaccess (and possibly a few more in the future) ?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague suggested to leave the files hidden and use the chflags command to show only the files I want.

`chflags nohidden .htaccess`

Or recursively in my development folder:

```
find ~/ -iname ".htaccess" | xargs chflags nohidden "{}"
```

Hope it helps you guys like it helped me!

Comment: This won't actually work. The Finder hides files if they have the hidden flag set **OR** if they are dotfiles. You can't override their being dotfiles by clearing the hidden flag - it's not even set on them to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

A handy keyboard shortcut to reveal files that begin with a . (dot) in Finder is:

`Shift` + `Command` + `.`

This toggles . (dot) files to show/ hide without needing to restart Finder.

You can also define an alias to quickly toggle hidden files within Finder:

```
alias AllFilesTRUE='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder'
alias AllFilesFALSE='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder
```

This answer was found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250638/how-to-reveal-dot-files-in-finder)